# Working of pre-fix increment in Java

Tags: java

What is the control flow of post-increment operator?

```
public class PostIncrement
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int a = 0;
        for(int i=0;i< 2 ;i++)
        {
            a =a++;     
        }

        for(int i=0 ;i< 1;i++)
        {
            a++;
        }

        System.out.println("Result2 :"+" "+a);        
    }

}
```

The results are like 0 and 1

Why is it so?

Comment: This code won't even compile since both loop variables are called `i`.

Comment: what more a even wikipedia discusses it.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Comment: `x=x++`. Yeah. Duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The postfix operator `++` executes after the statement completes.

The first time you print the value of `a` it prints zero because nothing has changed.
Next, you enter a for loop which executes once, incrementing the value of a. It doesn't actually matter that it is postincrement because there are no other instructions in that statement. The value of `a` is now `1`.

You print out `1`.

As an aside, your code doesn't actually work because the inner variable `i` is hiding the outer variable and so you will get a compiler error for redeclaring `i`. I assumed you mean a different variable here such as `j`.

Comment: Sorry for that..i wrote it wrongly..

Answer (score 0):

a++ would first use the value of a in that particular statement and then increment it.

for eg.

```
a=0;
sysout(a++);
sysout(a);
```

The result would be 0 and 1.

So in your case, if you had written the second for loop as

```
      for(int i=0 ;i< 1;i++)
         {
              sysout(a++);
         }
```

it will print 0 and 0 and 1.